How to use multithreaded FFTW inside an OpenMP Fortran code
I have a code that works fine that's compiled w/ gcc/gfortran-14 (installed via brew). The vast majority of the time is spent doing FFT via FFTW. In the critical part of the code I have this:
!$omp parallel
!$omp sections
!$omp section
       call fft(xi3d,xo3d,.false.,xip,layered_p)
!$omp section
       call fft(yi3d,yo3d,.false.,yip,layered_p)
!$omp section
       call fft(zi3d,zo3d,.false.,zip,layered_p)
!$omp end sections
!$omp sections
!$omp section
       x3d=n3d(:,:,:,1,1)*xo3d+n3d(:,:,:,2,1)*yo3d+n3d(:,:,:,3,1)*zo3d
!$omp section
       y3d=n3d(:,:,:,4,1)*xo3d+n3d(:,:,:,5,1)*yo3d+n3d(:,:,:,6,1)*zo3d
!$omp section
       z3d=n3d(:,:,:,7,1)*xo3d+n3d(:,:,:,8,1)*yo3d+n3d(:,:,:,9,1)*zo3d
!$omp end sections
!$omp sections
!$omp section
       call fft(rx3d,x3d,.true.,xp,layered_p)
!$omp section
       call fft(ry3d,y3d,.true.,yp,layered_p)
!$omp section
       call fft(rz3d,z3d,.true.,zp,layered_p)
!$omp end sections
!$omp end parallel

where x/y/zi3d and rx/y/z3d are real 3d arrays and all others are complex 3d arrays (all created with fftw_alloc_real/complex). The fft subroutine simply calls fftw_plan_dft_c2r_3d or fftw_plan_dft_r2c_3d depending on the third parameter (i.e. .true. or .false.).
I usually run w/ three threads. so the FFT are run in parallel. This works really well and the code does see an almost 3x performance improvement.
Now I'm trying to use OpenMP with FFTW itself. That is tell FFTW to use 2 or 3 threads in each fft instead of one. So at the start of the code I do the required initialization:
     if (fftw_init_threads().eq.0) then
       print *,'fftw has problem: fftw_init_threads'
     else
       call fftw_plan_with_nthreads(max(1,omp_get_max_threads()/3))
       print *,'each fftw will use ',max(1,omp_get_max_threads()/3),' threads'
   !   call omp_set_nested(.true.)
     endif

However, when I run the code (even after setting export OMP_NUM_THREADS=6 or export OMP_NUM_THREADS=3,2, the code runs slower. Setting to 6, top tells me only three processors are running. The other setting shows like 4.5 processors running, but in both cases the code runs slower than just using 3 threads and not using FFTW OpenMP.
The size of the arrays I'm using is 512x512x256. I'm on a MacBookPro w/ M1Pro and 32GB of memory.
Do I need the omp_set_nested(.true.) or not? What can I do to see all 6 processors pegged while doing the FFTW (which, in this code is over 95% of the time!)?
Any suggestions on what to try.

Setting omp_num_threads=6 will assign 6 threads to the outer parallel region. Most implementations of nested parallelism I have seen are not very well implemented. Most of the time, threads are recreated for each inner parallel region. I would try to execute the fft calls sequentially and use all threads for parallel execution inside of fft.

@Joachim Thanks. Bit surprised by the suggestion, since I would have thought using six threads on three sequential FFT would be slower than 2 threads per each FFT done concurrently. I suppose I could stack three FFT (FFTW allows this) and then just throw all 6 threads at that.

When benchmarking, also keep in mind that fftw with enabled threads takes a lot longer to create plans since it measures performance. See if storing and loading wisdom files helps.

@Homer512 Thanks. Yes, I have wisdom implemented. However, I'm running on a M1 Pro chip which FFTW claims doesn't have timing, so it falls back to ESTIMATE. The production code will probably run on x86 where wisdom will work. I would like to understand the bottleneck and how to get around it. I'll try stacking the 3d arrays tomorrow and see if it doesn't consume all six threads.

I've replicated the code and did some benchmarks. On my system (Intel i7-11800H), parallelization cannot exceed 150% speedup compared to single threaded. If I interpret the perf reports correctly (less than 1 instruction per cycle, large number of LLC misses), the code is simply bound by memory bandwidth, not CPU performance

@Homer512 Thanks. Not surprising it is memory bandwidth bound. Appreciate you reproducing and doing benchmarks. I tried to arrange the matrices so cache misses were minimal (for FFTW this says you have to twiddle the matrix indices because Fortran has column vs. C's row based matrix). Never looked closely at what FFTW does for multithread support.

From OpenMP perspective, you want to execute two nested parallel regions with 3 threads at the outer level which then execute n threads at the inner level. Starting with OpenMP 5.0, the use of nested-var and its API was deprecated and is now controlled either by setting max-active-levels-var, or by the elements in the nthreads-var list (3,n in your case). omp_get_max_threads() is defined to provide the head value of the nthreads-var list. So from serial context it will provide you 3.
In your code, you therefore either tell fftw to plan for execution with 2 threads (OMP_NUM_THREADS=6), but then execute with a single thread, or you tell fftw to plan for execution with 1 thread (OMP_NUM_THREADS=3,2) and then execute with 2 threads.
To plan properly for fftw execution, the tricky part is to access n from the list. You can spawn a parallel region to emulate your 3-sections region and pop the 3 from the nthreads-var list. At this point you can access the second value using omp_get_max_threads().
     if (fftw_init_threads().eq.0) then
       print *,'fftw has problem: fftw_init_threads'
     else
!$omp parallel
!$omp single
       call fftw_plan_with_nthreads(max(1,omp_get_max_threads()))
       print *,'each fftw will use ',max(1,omp_get_max_threads()),' threads'
!$omp end single
!$omp end parallel
     endif

GCC implements nesting based on a nthreads-var list at least since version 9, so you don't need to additionally call omp_set_nested

Thanks. Very good explanation of nesting. I see my mental model of how threads are created was wrong. Hope your solution works since it's trivial to implement. I'll try this and also stacking the three matrices so I'm always at one level of parallelization. For future reference, nthreads-var etc are well documented: link

This works, however I do have to set the environmental variable OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS=2 and OMP_NUM_THREADS=3,2. On the Mac, this does correctly produce FFTW plans with two threads per FFTW. When the code hits the SECTIONS part, it does initially saturate all six threads but then it soon becomes deadlocked and the code CPU use falls to zero. It doesn't crash, it just locks up. I don't have a linux box available, but I did install WSL on windows 11. Using the same setup, only three threads are busy. Other threads come and go, but do not do any work. I'll try stacking.

I tried recompiling FFTW with -enable-threads (instead of -enable-openmp). Included the fftw_threads library (instead of fftw_openmp) on main code. Hacked to tell the code to always use 2 threads for FFTW and did one level of OpenMP with three threads. On Mac, doesn't work. It spawns six threads. But half are sitting in _pthread_cond_wait. It never finishes one pass through FFTW when it its called fromSECTIONS. It does finish if I call FFTW outside of any OpenMP construct. Annoying.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15013395, plan creation is not thread-safe. Do you create the plan sequentially and only execute in parallel?

yes, I create the plans in a single thread and only execute in parallel.
